# Getting all rows of one table, and matching rows from another table where entries may not exist in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

so what I have is a database where records have an `ID` and a `YEAR` associated with them. Each `YEAR` will only have one record for each `ID`, but every `ID` doesn't necessarily exist in a given `YEAR`. So, what I'm trying to do is get a list of every record from my table for the 2018 `YEAR`, and get a certain value from the three previous years. My issue is that if a record from 2018 didn't exist in 2017, I won't get it at all. I want to just fill in NULL fields with a 0 or something, but still keep that `ID`.

What I have so far (which obviously doesn't work) is:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.VAL, c.VAL, d.VAL
FROM table as a, table as b, table as c, table as d
WHERE a.YEAR = 2018 AND b.YEAR = 2017 AND c.YEAR = 2016 AND d.YEAR = 2015 AND a.ID = b.ID AND b.ID = c.ID AND c.ID = d.ID;
```

I tried doing a join like:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.VAL FROM table as a LEFT JOIN table as b on a.ID = b.ID WHERE...
```

but that still showed the same issue. I should also mention I'm doing this in MS ACCESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       SUM(IIF(a.YEAR = 2018, a.VAL, 0)) as val_2018,
       SUM(IIF(a.YEAR = 2017, a.VAL, 0)) as val_2017,
       SUM(IIF(a.YEAR = 2016, a.VAL, 0)) as val_2016,
       SUM(IIF(a.YEAR = 2015, a.VAL, 0)) as val_2015
FROM table as a
WHERE a.YEAR IN (2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

If you only want rows where `2018` is present, then include:

```
HAVING MAX(a.YEAR) = 2018
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. What is the purpose of using SUM in this query?

Comment: @Jsqsh . . . An aggregation function is needed for an aggregation query.  `SUM()` seems like the appropriate one to use.  `MAX()` would probably also work.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand the data structure you're describing. The variable table below is my interpretation. If this is correct then the code below it should give you what you're looking for.

The key difference is the 'AND' in the 'ON' clause vs in the 'WHERE'. If you put the criteria in the 'WHERE' then you're essentially turning your LEFT OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN by asserting that the criteria must be true after the join is completed. Whereas in the 'ON' you're telling SQL that it must be true in order to do the join itself.

```
declare @tbl table ([year] int, [id] int, [someval] varchar(50))
insert into @tbl values (2018, 1, 'one')
insert into @tbl values (2018, 2, 'two')
insert into @tbl values (2017, 1, 'three')
insert into @tbl values (2016, 1, 'four')
insert into @tbl values (2015, 1, 'five')
insert into @tbl values (2015, 2, 'six')
insert into @tbl values (2015, 3, 'seven')

;with t2018 as(select * from @tbl where [year]=2018)
,t2017 as(select * from @tbl where [year]=2017)
,t2016 as(select * from @tbl where [year]=2016)
,t2015 as(select * from @tbl where [year]=2015)
select isnull(t2018.id,isnull(t2017.id,isnull(t2016.id,t2015.id))) as id,
     t2018.someval as [2018SomeVal],
     t2017.someval as [2017SomeVal], 
     t2016.someval as [2016SomeVal], 
     t2015.someval as [2015SomeVal]
from t2018
    full outer join t2017 on t2017.id = t2018.id
    full outer join t2016 on t2016.id = t2018.id
    full outer join t2015 on t2015.id = t2018.id
```

Comment: Ms Access uses a different syntax. I tried to convert what you wrote but wasn't able to.